# How to create SNS topic based on CloudWatch Container Insights?

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-cloudwatch, amazon-sns, amazon-cloudwatchlogs, aws-cloudwatch-log-insights

I know that we can use Cloud-Watch Container insights to collect and analyse metrics and logs from containers running on EKS or ECS.

But is it possible to create a SNS topic and send it to user emails if any web application failure occurs?

I have not tried any possible solution for this. So any kind of suggestion will help !!